# Custom Properties Panel BPMN Issue

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bpmn.io

I have added custom properties panel in BPMN but now I need to add custom dropdown also. But after adding custom properties panel section is showing, but when I expand magic properties its not showing any field also not showing any error.

**Screenshot:** https://pummy-kanhasoft.nimbusweb.me/share/7675055/u6ga9ufz4n152dyda6d1

**Using below versions:**
“react”: “18.0.0”,
“@bpmn-io/properties-panel”: “0.17.0”,
“bpmn-js-properties-panel”: “1.3.0”,

Here is my github code link and steps for custom properties which will show after build the project:

1. Just clone git url: https://github.com/pummy-kanhasoft/bpmn-custom
2. Then cd bpmn-custom directory
3. Then run the command npm i
4. Then run npm run build
5. Then run npm run start

Please follow these steps then after you will see magic properties, So after selecting **startEvent** and after every change you need to run 2 commands:

1. npm run build
2. npm run start

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code as text directly to the question, and [format it appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).